# sampling and weighting algorithms for political survey

Tags: survey, survey-weights, survey-sampling

I'd like to find a readable reference (code or algorithmic description) for the **sampling** (*méthode des quotas*) and **weighting** (*redressement des résultats bruts*) **algorithms** used in **political surveys**.

- In french the sampling method used in surveys is named *"méthode des quotas"* which means selecting a survey panel whose proportions of women, youths, labor workers, farmers, suburbans, left and right voters is approximately the same as in the population.
- And *"redressement des résultats bruts"* means we have a survey panel whose such proportions doesn't accord with the population, so we compute a weighting of each voter such that the weighted average of each variable accords with the truth. Then we use the same weights when computing the proportions of yes/no or left/right in the survey answer, and this is what we communicate to the press.

**What I want to do :** reproduce (in javascript) those algorithms used by survey institutes in order to demonstrate on a webpage how the political surveys really work. To achieve this, I'd like to find some open source packages implementing those algorithms (in any langage) or some algorithmic description of those.

Until now I found this big list of packages : https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/OfficialStatistics.html but I'm not sure of what I should look at.

---

Edit : I tried to implement a naive gradient descent algorithm for weighting and sampling, they hardly converge to a good local minimum when the number of variables to fit is $> 4$, too bad.

Do you know a better algorithm ?